# Addition assignment did not run as expected in Javascript's recursive functions

Tags: javascript, recursion

For the following functions that use addition assignment, the value of `ans` is always changed to 1 when an integer greater than 1 is passed

```js
let ans = 0;
function reduce(num){
    if(num == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    ans += reduce(num-1);
    return 1;
}
reduce(5);
console.log(ans); // 1
```

But when I save the recursive result to another variable first, the function works fine (`ans` will be changed to `num-1`)

```js
let ans = 0;
function reduce(num){
    if(num == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    let tmp=reduce(num-1);
    ans += tmp;
    return 1;
}
reduce(5);
console.log(ans); // 4
```

How does this happen? Is this a feature of Javascript or a bug in the environment?

I have tried similar C codes and they all behave the same

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int reduce(int num);
int ans;
int main(){
    ans = 0;
    reduce(5);
    printf("%d",ans); // 4
}

int reduce(int num){
    if(num == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    int tmp=reduce(num-1);
    ans += tmp;
    // ans += reduce(num-1);
    return 1;
}
```

Environment:

- Microsoft Edge    97.0.1072.55
- JavaScript    V8 9.7.106.18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because in JavaScript `ans += reduce(num-1)` is evaluated as:

```
ans = ans + reduce(num-1)
```

and not as:

```
ans = reduce(num-1) + ans;
```

(See [(13.15.2) Runtime semantics: evaluation](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) in the ECMAScript specs).

So `ans` is *evaluated* before the recursive call is made, and it is that *evaluated* value that is used as the operand of the addition.

You can avoid such unexpected behaviour by avoiding functions with [*side-effects*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). A [pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) recursive solution would be:

```js
function reduce(num) {
    if (num < 2) {
        return 0;
    }
    return reduce(num-1) + 1;
}
let ans = reduce(5);
console.log(ans); // 4
```

Comment: it's really tricky ...

Comment: That's why never use global scope variable inside recursive function.